# Why the Preview window in Animator Controller is empty?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Not sure what happened. Until now I saw the character in the Preview window and I could hit play and see the preview. Now it's empty. No matter what transition I click on the preview window is empty.

[image: Preview window at the right bottom is empty]

Comment: Try to drag your avatar over to the preview and drop it there.

Comment: @Hristo Tried it before it didn't help. Only doing reimport all or restarting unity and loading the project over again helped but that is not a solution for the problem. I'm not sure yet why and how it happened.  Strange.

Comment: I presume that you also tried dropping in the Model/Prefab as well. In that case I'm out of ideas.